# What is LINQ to SQL template? What is the advantage of it?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql, templates

What is LINQ to SQL template? What is the advantages of it?

Comment: And what kind of Template do you mean? Project Template? (And please don't ask me to write one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you mean the "**Linq to SQL class template**" it is the template you need for creating a DBML. You can graphically add the tables to the DBML and SQLMetal then transforms the DBML into a DataContext, tables, and data types.